# Python lxml method tostring with selfclosing tag <br/>

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I have the following Code and Output (without closing br-tag):

```
from lxml import html 
root = html.fromstring('<br/>')
html.tostring(root)
```

> Output : `'<br>'`

However, I have expected some similar to this (adding also a closing tag for this self-closing element):

```
from lxml import html 
root = html.fromstring('<a/>')
html.tostring(root)
```

> Output : `'<a></a>'`

Is there a way to produce the wanted output or just `'<br/>'` ?

Maybe somebody could also point to the relevant part in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is not XML compliant and this is one of the places where that shows up. A break is `<br>`. Since a break element does not usually have internal content (attributes or text) it does not need to be written as an enclosing `<br/>` or `<br></br>` (although most browsers will accept both). You can change the output method to get XML compliance.

```
html.tostring(root, method='xml')
```

This could negatively impact other parts of the document, though.